# Problem in booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, sata

I have been having problem in booting(loading) Ubuntu 18.04.

The last time I had problem with Ubuntu was mmx64.efi file was missing, I found the solution and added efi file manually to load under secure boot.

This worked for a while but now I am again facing the problem with screen turning as shown in [[image 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5aWU.jpg) after turning on the laptop.

I searched a solution to turn SATA mode from RST opane to AHCI and it worked but only for one time as when I turned off the laptop and turned on again later I again had the problem with screen getting stuck at acer logo. Now I switched back the SATA mode and earlier problem again arised so I again changed SATA mode to AHCI and this time it loaded grub menu and opened ubuntu with recovery mode but when I again use my laptop, I have to repeat the process.

I am using Acer aspire series laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.

Someone please help me with this issue, I am highly confused. Is there a problem with my Ubuntu installation as these problem keep ccoming?

Comment: Are you using Dual boot?

Comment: no, I am only using Ubuntu

Comment: Try boot-repair

Comment: I have tried, but it only worked for sometime and problem kept coming.